# Get / Set only specific bits in a long

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have a 48 bit struct with several fields that I want to be able to read and manipulate. I think i got the getter part, but I am struggling with the setter. Here is some sample code:

Question is, for the setter, how can I just set specific bits without affecting the others. My understanding is that accomplished by bit shifting and some mask operations.

For example:

```
    public long data = 0x00;

    public byte val1
    {
        get => (byte)(data >>0 & 3); //Bit 0-1
    }
    public byte val2 //Bit 2-9
    {
        get => (byte)(data >> 2 & 0x3FC); //I think this works?
        set
        {
           // ?
        }
    }
```

Basically I am trying to read / insert a value (int16, int32, byte, etc) into that long. I tried using BitVector but the biggest section is 16 bits and a couple of the fields are bigger than that. (24 bits).

Comment: `set { data = (data & ~0x3FC) | (value << 2); }`

Comment: "//I think this works?" - I think you've done the shift and the and in the wrong order (or alternatively, in this case: just lose the and, since the cast to byte is the same as &0xFF)

Answer (score 1):

untested but:

```
const long mask = 0x3FC;
long i64 = value;
data = (data & ~mask) | (i64 << 2);
```